# Algorithm for comparator with multi product results

Tags: algorithm, comparison

I would like to implement an application that creates customized packages starting from a user's search.

For example, if the user has a sum of money and wants to assemble a computer, the system must return the best possible combination of components being in that price. For example, the user indicates that requires a processor, a mainboard, a RAM and an HDD: He must spend at most $ 1,000.

Then, the application will search and display the best combination for the user (each product has a weight - some kind of ranking - and value).

Which algorithm you advise me to do this research?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like Bin packing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: It is not bin packing, this is called the "multiple choice knapsack problem". Knapsack where the items are grouped (processors, motherboards...) with the additional constraint that exactly 1 item from each group must be selected. Note that the problem may be more complex than you describe, albegali - not every processor works with every motherboard, and so on. Do you also need to consider such things?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I considered that case, I filter elements before comparison.